# Get Value of Dynamically Added HiddenField

Tags: asp.net, hidden-field

I have a page where I'm dynamically adding HiddenFields through code behind.  I'm adding each of these HiddenFields (HF) from a list, the code I have to try and get the value of this list later is:

```
// Get the name of the hidden field using a specific cell in a grid.
string controlName = "hidden_value_" + grdMyGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
HiddenField field = (HiddenField)this.FindControl(controlName);
string fieldValue = field.Value;
```

However `field` gets returned as null.  I've tried `this.Page.FindControl` but this has the same result.

So what I'm wondering is it because of where the `HiddenFields` are in the Source?   Here is an example of the positioning, with the HF's being outside of the main HTML.  If this is the case how can I actually get these fields?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="head">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Random script here, not important
    </script>
<body>

    // Main body of my code, lots of different controls.  Not connected to
    // the HiddenFields at the very bottom.

</body>
</html>
<asp:HiddenField id='hidden_value_MyValue1' runat='server' value='1' /><asp:HiddenField id='hidden_value_MyValue2' runat='server' value='2' /><asp:HiddenField id='hidden_value_MyValue3' runat='server' value='3' />
```

**EDIT - UPDATED CODE**
This is how I am now adding my hidden values to the page

```
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    string hiddenValueControl = "<input type='hidden' id='hidden_value_" + product.Description +
                                                "' runat='server' value='" + product.AlphaKey + "' />";
                    productLiteral.Text = productLiteral.Text + hiddenValueControl;
                }
```

How can I then get one of these values?  I've tried this but it ends up returning null

```
         string tempProductId =
                     Request.Form["hidden_value_" + "MyProductName"];
```

Comment: FWIW, the fact that MVC supports using WebForms as well, is a compatibility feature to allow you gradually migrate an existing codebase. It's not intended that you create entirely new WebForms code. If you want to use WebForms, then just stick with WebForms, but if you're going to use MVC, then please use it.

Comment: Hi Chris, was that comment meant for this thread?

Comment: Yes. You tagged this post as asp.net-mvc, but all this code is Web Forms.

Comment: Whoops incorrect tagging!  Meant to just be ASP.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...I'm dynamically adding HiddenFields through code behind...

Be sure that you are adding these early enough in the Page life cycle (before Page_Load), otherwise they will not be retrievable during Postbacks, because they will not have been added to the ViewState properly.

See [the ASP.NET Page life cycle overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article on MSDN for more information.  It recommends using the Page_PreInit event to add / re-add dynamic controls (although most of the time I see people use Page_Init without issues).

It would be helpful if you showed the code where you're dynamically adding the HiddenField controls, just to confirm this theory.

Additionally, the markup you showed is a little confusing.  You say that you are dynamically adding the HiddenFields, but your markup shows at least one that's created declaratively.  It's not really normal to place HTML controls outside of the `<html>` tags.  You should probably move them inside.  And make sure that the HiddenField control is inside a `<form runat="server">` tag.

---

After your edit, I see that it seems there is some confusion with how to dynamically add controls to ASP.NET pages.  You don't want to build the *text* of the ASP.NET server control markup.  You can just build the actual control, using the web control classes, and then add it to a container on your Page.

What you want to do is add a PlaceHolder control at the bottom of your Page (wherever you want the HiddenFields to be):

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="hiddenControlContainer" runat="server" />
```

Then you would create and add controls to it using similar logic to what you had, but rather than building strings, you'll build controls:

```
foreach (var product in products)
{
    HiddenField productField = new HiddenField();
    productField.ID = "hidden_value_" + product.Description;
    productField.Value = product.AlphaKey;

    hiddenControlContainer.Controls.Add(productField);
}
```

*Note: As I mentioned above, you should do this is* `Page_Init`, *in order to make sure it can be retrieved later.*

Then you would retrieve the control like this:

```
HiddenField myField = (HiddenControl)hiddenControlContainer.FindControl("hidden_value_" + "MyProductName");
```

Comment: The markup shown is actually from doing View Source, so it's what has been generated.  The procedure to add them is done in my code behind.  I will look at everything else when I get a moment

Comment: @MattR Oh. Then it's not being processed by the ASP.NET engine at all. Otherwise, it would be a normal `<input type="hidden">` HTML element. Your rendered output should never have the "asp:" controls. You need to make sure that's inside the server form tag I mentioned, and put it within the `<html>` tags.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've managed to get the inputs to go inside the HTML.  I've updated the form with the new code at the bottom.  How can I get the values for a specific item?

Comment: Hey, @MattR.  I've updated my answer - thanks for taking the time to follow up!